# Overlaying am image on top of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to overlay a logo on top of a background image and I'm having a bit of trouble with it. Here is my html for the background image; the javascript makes the image refresh every second so it is like a video stream. The dublin-rememberance-floor2 is the image, there is some other javascript that gets this image from a database and puts it here full screen. The logo is logo.svg, I want this to go up in the left hand top corner but at the moment it is just going in behind the background and I have tried a couple of methods without success.

```
    <body>
        <img class="fullBG" evercam='dublin-rememberance-floor2' refresh="1000" alt="" /> <div class="logo">
    <img height="25" src="http://www.evercam.io/img/logo.svg" border="0" width="175" alt="http://www.evercam.com/" />
</div>

width="175" alt="http://www.evercam.com/" />   
        <img />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                Evercam.setApiUrl('http://api.evercam.io/v1');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Here is my css for the fullBG and logo;

```
    .fullBG {

        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 1;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;                
    }
.logo{
    position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

I changed my css and this seemed to work

```
.fullBG {

        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        overflow: auto;        
        width:100%;
        height:100%;                
    }
.logo{
    position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS for the background image?

Comment: why not just use the background image as a background to body and absolutely position the logo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nBn3D/

Comment: @abhitalks, I was just thinking of trying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is that you can give z-index of logo > z-index of background so it will come on top of background..

Comment: Thanks I removed the z-index from background and added it to the logo, that worked!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should position your a href link of logo also absolute.
another thing there is no separate closing img as you have done and trying to put "a href" in between of images.